# href links in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, href

In CakePHP,if i give href links as href="/css/main.css" it is not refering to the css folder in the webroot. Only when I mention href="http://localhost/cake/app/webroot/css/main.css" the css gets applied.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" media="screen,projection" />
```

This does not apply the specied css.

What is the reason for this?
Why is the code not identifying the correct folder?

Answer (score 5):

Because it starts with a /, it is treated as an absolute path (from the root of the site). The browser translates it to

```
http://localhost/css/main.css
```

You can either specify the correct absolute path

```
/cake/app/webroot/css/main.css
```

or the full path

```
http://localhost/cake/app/webroot/css/main.css
```

or a relative path, for example

```
../css/main.css
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $html->css('main');
```

[BOOK](http://book.cakephp.org/view/206/Inserting-Well-Formatted-elements#css-831)

[API](http://api.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelpercss)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using core helper? It will generate required path to CSS file  [Inserting Well-Formatted elements](http://book.cakephp.org/view/206/Inserting-Well-Formatted-elements#css-831)

And check main configuration file(/app/config/core.php), maybe you are not using mod_rewrite. Check core.php for commented this line Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));

Answer (score 0):

If your absolute URL looks like

```
http://localhost/cake/app/webroot/css/main.css
```

and your URL is

```
/css/main.css
```

I suppose the browser translates the URL you gave to

```
http://localhost/css/main.css
```

*(you can check that with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), "net" tab for instance)*

If that's the case, you should :

- use a relative URL with no leading /
- use an absolute URL that refers to the root URL

But, in my opinion, using the URL that starts with '`http://`' is the best way to be sure that your CSS inclusion is always OK, no matter which directory or URL you are into...

Comment: well, if I use url starting with http://, I have a problem. When I develop it and give it to someone else, he must be able to run the application  without changing the code..
For I may have it in a folder called cake, but he might have a different folder name. so I thought there might be a way to apply the css with just using /css/main.css

Comment: this URL could be defined in a configuration file, and given to your views (if you have some kind of bootstrap code with Cake, or a Controller-class inherited by every Controller of your application, this might me the right place to do that) ; or there is probably a way with the framework you're using to determiner the base URL of the application (I don't use Cake myself, so I can't give you any hint about that ; sorry)

Answer (score 0):

A function like this to define a BASEURL allows you to only update in one place.. I use something like...

```
define("DEVELOPMENT", true);
```

function setReporting() 
{
if (DEVELOPMENT) 
    {
            define("BASEURL", "http://localhost/localDir", true);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
    }
    else 
    {
            define("BASEURL", 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], true);
            error_reporting(0);
    }
}
setReporting();

Comment: In which file should this base url be defined?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy cake, the url should just be /css/main.css as the server's DocumentRoot will point to the cake/app/webroot directory.

I suggest reading [this article from Cake's online docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/308/Installing-CakePHP) for more info. Note that this article refers to the 1.1 version of Cake, but should work in 1.2 as well.

Good luck!